# Inserting/Updating rows cause return from debug mode

Tags: c#, oracle

can you help me with inserting rows into Oracle database in C#..

I have foreach and in it I just make sql query.. Then when I try to insert into database (with support of debbuging), first row insert in couple of miliseconds but the second insert/update is about 5 minutes.. All the magic is at line where is cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
With the second row inserted/updated the debbuger return focus to the application and then after cca 5 minutes return back to debbuger.. But it's simple update so there is no so much time needed..

```
        using (var connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionTNS)) 
        {
            connection.Open();
            var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

            int rowsInserted = 0;


            foreach (var item in _tableNameAndColumnsList)
            {
                if (item.Replace)
                {
                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = connection;
                        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TABLE TEST WHERE id_test = "+id_test+" ";
                        rowsInserted += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            transaction.Commit();
            MessageBox.Show("Changed " + rowsInserted + " database rows...");
```

Do you have same problem someone? 
Thanks Lukas

Comment: Please always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: This does not look like a complete `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new connection in every loop which is not required and you should avoid it for network consumption

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    foreach (var item in _tableNameAndColumnsList)
    {
        if (item.Replace)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TABLE TEST WHERE id_test = "+id_test+" "; /*Assuming this is only test command*/
            rowsInserted += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Not to forgot, Please use the parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks I will try.. I know about parametrized query but now this is my priority.. :) I will check it

Comment: No it didn't help.. I don't understand why the first query is executing OK and another stop.. It looks like the first after executes close connection or something similiar..

Comment: Oki, Oracle SQL Developer need to commited changes.. My application was waiting for the timeout of SQL Developer so there were error..  Thanks all for help :)